# NFC can’t scanned by app, but the phone is recognize it

Tags: iphone, security, automator, nfc

I want to have my NFC cards (I have 10+ card that I need every day) on my iPhone 13 Pro, and use it instead of theme

Office, metro, room door, automated actions, …

I tried many apps but they didn’t recognize the NFC tags (cards) and they can’t scan them.

**BUT**, If I go to `Shortcuts > Automation > + > Personal automation > NFC` and tap on **scan**, It recognizes the tag.
`->` **The tag is supported by the phone**

So here is my question:

1- how can I read such NFC tags?

2- Is there any app for such usage? I mean scanning NFC tags and storing them for later uses, the phone acts instead of the tag

3- how can I make my tags like this?

I have created some NFC tags for my personal automation and IoT devices but they act normally and can be read by apps